# Converting MySQL Query over to SQLalchemy query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to port all raw SQL scripts over from my server that was running using a simple BASH script so I can handle the data with python and sqlalchemy but this one script below refuses to port. I have also included below this my closest attempt in replicating it.

If anyone has any ideas where I am going wrong or if you can replicate it please feel free.

Also note some tables have bean replaced with filler names.

-----MYSQL-----

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT CONCAT('{URL}', TBL1.ColumID) AS 'Link',
    TBL1.ColumID AS CaseID,
    TBL1.ColumType AS 'Abuse Type',
    TBL1.Status AS 'Status',
    TBL1.Role AS 'Queue', TBL1.CreationDate, TBL1.LastUpdated, @LAST_TOUCHED:=
    (SELECT from_unixtime((max(unix_timestamp(LAST_UPDATED))))
        FROM TBL2
        WHERE TBL1.ColumID = CaseID
        AND (NOTE_TYPE = 'communication'
            OR NOTE_SUBTYPE IS NULL)) AS last_touched, ((unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(LAST_UPDATED))/3600/24) AS Age,
    CASE
    WHEN isnull(@LAST_TOUCHED) THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'Y'
    END AS Touched
    FROM TBL1
    WHERE TBL1.ROLE REGEXP '{ROLE Filler}'
    AND STATUS REGEXP 'RESOLVED|DELETED' =0) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.Age > 2
order by tbl.Age desc
```

------Failed Python Code-----

```
query = select([
        TBL1.c.caseid.label('CaseID'),
        TBL1.c.casetype.label('Type'),
        TBL1.c.STATUS.label('Status'),
        TBL1.c.ROLE.label('Queue'),
        TBL1.c.CREATION_DATE,
        TBL1.c.LAST_UPDATED,
        (func.from_unixtime(
            func.max(
                func.unix_timestamp(
                    TBL2.c.LAST_UPDATED))).filter(
        TBL2.c.caseid == TBL1.c.caseid).filter(
        (TBL2.c.NOTE_TYPE == '{notetype}') | 
        (TBL2.c.NOTE_SUBTYPE == None)).label("LAST_TOUCHED")
        )]).where(
        (TBL1.c.ROLE == '{rolename}') &
        (TBL1.c.STATUS != 'RESOLVED') |
        (TBL1.c.STATUS != 'DELETED'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, double check that you really have to do this. Are you doing this to include your query in a webserver, or to extract data for analysis? If it's the latter, just use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('{connection string}')
df = pd.read_sql_query("{insert your complicated query here}", engine)
```

Comment: I'm doing this for both reasons. I intend to use the query to first gather analytics and then use those analytics in a dashboard functionality.

As for pandas I am going to give this a try and see if it solves my problem. It looks like it could be a two birds one stone solution.